# Do Haste and Rage stack their effects?

Tags: clash-of-clans

**Do units benefit of both the bonuses of Haste and Rage if they are affected by them at the same time?** If not, which one has priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a Haste Spell were to be placed along with a Rage Spell, their
>   speed increase would stack.

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Haste_Spell